# Flask Blueprint is not using correct template folder

Tags: python, flask

I created a flask app using the flask application model.  However the blueprint is not looking in the `template_folder` for the blueprint.  My app is below.

```
app_folder/
   app.py
   application/
      __init__.py (with app_context() blueprints registered here)
      routes/
         bp_route.py
            bp_route = Blueprint(...,template_folder='admin')
            def home()
            .....
            return render_template('index.html')
    template/
        admin/
           index.html
```

If i move the index file to just under template it works.  The template_folder is being ignored.  In order for me to get the desired outcome I have to use `return render_template('admin/index.html')`.  Why is template_folder being ignored?

Comment: "template_folder – A folder with templates that should be added to the app’s template search path. __The path is relative to the blueprint’s root path.__" so try `template_folder='template'` or `template_folder='template/admin'`

Comment: Why template_folder is being ignored? Because that's where `render_template` expects  to find HTML files... like it's in the name `render_**template**`

Answer (score 2):

I had to change the template_folder to  `template_folder='../templates/admin/'`